# Number Guessing Game with payment

Tags: sequences-and-series, game-theory

> **Original problem:**
>
> Alice chooses a positive integer $x\in[1,100]$ and Bob tries to guess it.
>
> Each turn Bob can guess a number $y$ and pay $y$ dollor(s) to Alice.
>
> If $y=x$ game stops, otherwise Alice will tell Bob $y>x$ or $y<x$.
>
> What's the minimum expectation payment for Bob to know the random number $n$.

I tried to find the answer of **general case**.

---

**My rough Attempts:**

Let $\mathrm{E}(n)$ be the total payment under the optimal strategy, define $\mathrm{cost}(m,n)$ as the minimum price when $m\leq x\leq n$, so $\mathrm{E}(n)=\mathrm{cost}(1,100)$.

Then we can write the recurrence equation.

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{cost}(m,n)&=\ 0 \quad \texttt{when}\ m\geq n,\ \texttt{otherwise:}\\
\mathrm{cost}(m,n)&= \min_{m\leq l\leq n} \left(l + \frac{l-m}{n-m+1} \mathrm{cost}(m,l-1) + \frac{n-l}{n-m+1} \mathrm{cost}(l+1,n)\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

Then I use some Mathematica codes to get the answer.

```
cost[m_, n_] := 0 /; m >= n;
cost[m_, n_] := cost[m, n] =
  Min@Table[l + (l - m) cost[m, l - 1]/(n - m + 1)
              + (n - l) cost[l + 1, n]/(n - m + 1), {l, m, n}]
cost[1, 100]
Table[cost[1, i], {i, 1, 10}]*Range[10]
```

$$\begin{array}{c|cc}
\text{n} & 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&100 \\
\hline
\mathrm{E}(n)&\cfrac{0}{1}&\cfrac{2}{2}&\cfrac{6}{3}&\cfrac{13}{4}&\cfrac{22}{5}&\cfrac{35}{6}&\cfrac{52}{7}&\cfrac{72}{8}&\cfrac{96}{9}&\cfrac{123}{10}&\cfrac{26190}{100}\\
\end{array}\\$$

I have no idea about this sequence.

**Can we find a close form of $\mathrm{E}(n)$?**

Comment: Does Alice makes a random choice, or are you assuming that she makes the choice that is most expensive to Bob (so to earn more money)?

Comment: @mlc ,random, uniform distribution from 1-n... The game theory version too hard I think.